# iPad - Which user touched the screen?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, multi-touch

When someone points a finger, his finger is pointing in a specific direction, right ?
ok, so when a user touches the iPad, i would like to know where that touch came from. I am not saying on the iPad. I mean where is the user physically positioned compared to the iPad.
You could say "easy ! You just check the orientation of the iPad and you got it."
There's the problem. In my scenario there are 2 users, each on a different side of the iPad, and my objective is to determine which of the 2 users touched the iPad.
I know that on Microsoft Surface, you can determine that information by looking at the shadow created by the finger on the surface. Unfortunately, it can't work on the iPad since the touches aren't recovered by cameras.

Comment: It seems like you already know this can't be done.

Comment: Your fingers will yield the same capacitance regardless of where they're oriented. Not going to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Unfortunately, it can't work on the iPad since the touches aren't recovered by cameras.

Well, yes. You've answered your own question. The touch event is just an event on the surface of the screen. If both users can touch anywhere on the screen, you've got no way of knowing who did it.

You could possibly ask player 1 to use one finger and player 2 to use two fingers, but this would be a bit unfair on player 2, or you could read the touches as miniature drags and guess that each player was pushing away from themselves, but that may not work in the context of your game.

(I've assumed you are talking about a game)

Comment: The problem here is not having no cameras, but that you'll get no raw data. This is possible with devices running Android or custom products (there are some publications covering this topic).

Comment: Great idea !!! Thanks ! I think i will go with the miniature drags. thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

Since you are not going to get the raw data from the iPad, I doubt that this is possible.

Comment: What do you mean by raw data in this context?

Comment: A touch point actually isn't just `one` point (as your finger tip isn't that tiny). There are some underlying mechanisms, that will give you the center (or the most likely targeted area) of these points

Comment: Ok, interesting stuff, thanks. I imagine that has some interesting applications!